# Converting Decimal to String to Decimal

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string

I copied this code from another post.  I tried the example, however, I am getting a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.  From what I have read, this error happens when trying to use an object that has been deallocated, but I just don't see where I am doing that:

The call
...

```
float weighted_average = num_of_passes / total_of_all_passes;
NSString *newNumber = [[NSString alloc] init];
newNumber = [self formattedStringWithDecimal:weightedAverage]; //weighted average (float) = 15.875145
```

...

The Function

```
- (NSString *)formattedStringWithDecimal:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; //two deimal spaces
    [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp]; //round up


   NSString *result =[NSString stringWithString:[formatter stringFromNumber:decimalNumber]];
    [formatter release];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message? Enable NSZombieEnabled for your executable first.

Comment: And how is formatterstringFromNumber defined? I am not able to run the code. Please add the code. How is weightedAverage initialized?

Comment: that should have read: [formatter stringFromNumber

Comment: I have enabled NSZombie but the program still crashes.

Comment: NSZombieEnabled will not prevent a crash, but gives you information about what deallocated object was used.

Comment: Both your initialization of `newNumber` and your use of `stringWithString:` are unnecessary. You don't need to initialize a variable to hold a pointer to one object before you put a pointer to a different object in it, and since you didn't release the object you initialized the variable with, you leaked it. Since you're not using that initial string at all, cut it out and simply initialize the variable with the object returned by `formattedStringWithDecimal:`.

Comment: As for `stringWithString:`, when you're passing it a string, you already have a string, so you generally don't need to create another string with it. When you're not passing it a string, that's a mistake; you must pass it a string. The only time it's worth using is when going from mutable to immutable (e.g., when you build a string as a mutable string and then want to return an immutable string) or vice versa. Basically, whenever you would use `copy` or `mutableCopy` but want an exception when the string to copy is `nil`. Whenever you don't need a copy, just use the string you have.

Comment: Also, the Zombies template in Instruments is far better than NSZombieEnabled, since you can look back over the entire history of the zombie object. With NSZombieEnabled, you can only examine the present; Instruments lets you look at the past and the present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the method like this:

```
newNumber = [self formattedStringWithDecimal:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:15.434]];
```

You've tried to pass a primitive, but the method expects an object: an NSDecimalNumber. You've got to use the static convenience method numberWithFloat to create an object of that type.

And by the way, I have the feeling that

```
newNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%.2f", 15.434];
```

could achieve the same result with less lines of code. Note this will not round up your number though.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an autoreleased object. Does the function that uses it retain it? If not, it could be released and then later (later run loop) its trying to be (re)used. Agreed on the enabling zombies to spot that kind of thing.